# How to run Google Chrome as two unique Google Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, multiple-monitors

I have one PC which has dual monitor on left monitor it has to show www.example1.com and on right monitor it has to show www.example2.com, where the left screen is touch input and the other one is not.

each screen uses camera for left screen camera1, for right screen camera2. Now when i run Google Chrome 2 new windows the main problem is that it always using camera1 as it remembers.

How can i run two separate Google Chrome on same machine with there own custom settings? (so that i can tell Google chrome on left window follow camera1 never use camera2, and on right screen Google Chrome always to use camera2)

(i cant use firefox, opera. Only Google chrome browser is allowed to be used with some terms and condition related issue)

Comment: In the linux version you would  use xrandr and  something along the lines of   google-chrome --xrandr-set-left  (or right)  ---possibly other options  not entirely sure how power shell on windows would handle this tho.

Comment: Its Windows 8.1 Pro (cant use Linux and Chromium for license violation issues, i am only allowed to use Windows 8.1 Pro with Google Chrome)

Comment: Look into commands in powershell then  -- not sure HOW open source licenses or linux or chromium would be a violation tho tbh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one possible way that comes in my mind.
You first have to set up a new profile in chrome. Now copy a shortcut to your Google Chrome Browser and go to its preferences. Find out where the dictionary of that newly created profile is and what name it has. Go to "%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data" and find it out ("default" is the default user). Once you have the name you have to add following parameters to the Google Chrome shortcut:

```
--profile-directory="%localappdata%\google\Chrome\User Data\[DICTIONARY OF PROFILE HERE]"
```

Open your default profile browser in monitor 1 and your newly created profile browser on monitor 2 (or vice versa). I think that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, I misunderstand the question, but how is this problem not resolved by setting a different src attribute on the html element on the page responsible for displaying the cameras on each different site?